# Bat file to modify Variable Value in a file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

`For a file deferredreportsdaemon.ini
it has content:

```
ApplicationDatabaseClass=com.systems.pool.MySQLConnectionManager
ApplicationDatabaseUser=administrator
ApplicationDatabasePassword=test
ApplicationDatabaseName=envdata
ApplicationDatabaseServer=eis-mysql0:3308
```

I want to create a bat file which will promt for new value for variable ApplicationDatabaseName and update in file after i enter the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will rename the current `deferredreportsdaemon.ini` to `deferredreportsdaemon.ini.old` and will create a new `deferredreportsdaemon.ini`.

Note: this is probably not the ***best, most efficient*** way to do this but it seems to work for me. Also, you will need to add more error checking since I don't do any here...

```
@echo off

set /P DBNAME="Please enter an Application Database Name: "
set INI=deferredreportsdaemon.ini
set OLD=%INI%.old

copy /Y %INI% %OLD%
del %INI%

FOR /F "delims=\= tokens=1,2" %%K IN (%OLD%) DO (
    IF "%%K" NEQ "ApplicationDatabaseServer" echo %%K=%%L >>%INI%
)

echo ApplicationDatabaseServer=%DBNAME% >>%INI%
```

Initial ini file content:

```
ApplicationDatabaseClass=com.systems.pool.MySQLConnectionManager
ApplicationDatabaseUser=administrator
ApplicationDatabasePassword=test
ApplicationDatabaseName=envdata
ApplicationDatabaseServer=eis-mysql0:3308
```

After running the script and entering `my_database_name`:

```
ApplicationDatabaseClass=com.systems.pool.MySQLConnectionManager 
ApplicationDatabaseUser=administrator 
ApplicationDatabasePassword=test 
ApplicationDatabaseServer=eis-mysql0:3308 
ApplicationDatabaseName=my_database_name
```

Comment: Thanks JWR, You're awesome ! Just wanted to check, it there any method where i cannot change the variable order ? Thanks a zillion, and keep up good stuff :)